# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast (singly linked list methods in C)

Tags: c, list

I'm using a singly linked list struct in place of an array to calculate averages of grades inputted via CSV files in my program. However, when calling methods that should be working, I can't assign what they return. I'm using the following to methods in my main:

```
int SLL_pop(struct List *list) {
    /* remove and return the first item of the list */
    struct Node *node = list->head;
    int item = node->item;
    list->head = node->next;
    if (SLL_empty(list)) {
        list->tail = NULL;
    }
    free(node);
    return item;
}

int SLL_getID(struct List *list) {
    /* returns ID of head node */
    struct Node *node = list->head;
    int id = node->id;
    if (SLL_empty(list)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return id;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i = 0;
    FILE *inf;
    struct List list = SLL_new();
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        inf = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        int studentID = 0;
        int grade = 0;
        if(inf == NULL){
            printf("No such file found/n");
            exit(1);
        }
        while(1) {
            int ret = fscanf(inf, "%d,%d", &studentID, &grade);
            if(ret == 2){
                SLL_insert(&list, studentID, grade);
                c++;
            }
            else if(ret == EOF){
                fclose(inf);
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("No match.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    SLL_print(&list);
    FILE *outf;
    outf = fopen("finalgrade.csv", "w");
    if (outf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(SLL_empty == 0){
        int sum = 0;
        int id = SLL_getID;
        sum+=SLL_pop;
        sum+=SLL_pop;
        sum+=SLL_pop;
        float avg = sum/3;
        fprintf(outf, "%d,%f\n", id, avg);
    }
    fclose(outf);
}
```

Compiling error:

```
amazingCalculator.c: In function 'main':
amazingCalculator.c:170:12: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   int id = SLL_getID;
            ^
amazingCalculator.c:171:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   sum+=SLL_pop;
      ^
amazingCalculator.c:172:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   sum+=SLL_pop;
      ^
amazingCalculator.c:173:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   sum+=SLL_pop;
      ^
          ^
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, I'm fairly certain the methods are correct because I've tested them beforehands. Am I not assigning what they return properly within my while loop? I'm new to C and the concept of pointers.

Comment: Call like `int id = SLL_getID(aList_pointer);`

Comment: My bad, I pasted incomplete code. The parameter was there, but it was a list not a pointer to the list.